# Proof for triangle inequality for case $x+y<0$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Here's the attempt in case $x+y<0$:

In case $$x+y<0,$$ it must be true that $$(x<0\wedge y<0)$$
$$x\in \mathbb{R}\text{ is negative IFF }-x\in \mathbb{R}^+$$
$$x + y < 0 < -(x + y) = (-x)+(-y) = x + y < |x| + y < |x| + |y| \ (\forall x\land \forall y)\in \mathbb{R}$$
Does this looks right?

Comment: How does $x+y<0$ imply $x<0$ and $y<0$?

Comment: Would both not have to be negative so that x+y<0?

Comment: @user $-1$, $+1/2$

Comment: Your MathJax code looked like something done by a lunatic.  I cleaned it up.  Please look at my edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $x+y < 0$ does not imply that $x < 0 \land y<0$. (For example: $x=-10$, $y=9$.)

Your remark that $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is negative iff $-x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ is correct.

Your equality $(-x)+(-y) = x + y$ is mistaken. Note that you have $x + y < 0 < \ldots x + y < \ldots$. That doesn't work.

Finally, note that $x < |x|$ is not necessarily true. You want $x \leq |x|$.

Comment: To make the first correction, when $$x+y < 0$$, 
It is a possibility that 
x < 0 and y > 0 , 
x > 0 and y < 0 
x < 0 and y < 0
This implies that at least x or y is less than 0.

Comment: The only reason why isn't -x = x I can think of is because 
Suppose x = -8 then -(x) must be 8. But x = -8 is not equal to -x = 8
$$is-x = |x|?$$

Comment: For  $$ x + y < 0$$, at least x or y is less than 0.
$$x + y < -x + y < (-x) + (-y) \leq |x| + (-y) \leq |x| + |y|$$

Answer (score 0):

$-|x| \leq x \leq |x|$
and $-|y| \leq y \leq |y|$ $\implies$ $-|x|-|y| \leq x+y \leq |x|+|y|$ $\implies$ $|x+y| \leq |x| +|y|$ for any real $x,y$

The last implication comes from the fact:
$|x| \leq a \leftrightarrow -a \leq x \leq a$ for some $a \geq 0$